# Can the LocalSystem account impersonate any user ? Even if the user is not logged on?

Tags: .net, windows-services, impersonation

I have a Windows service running as LocalSystem that needs to access some network resources. I found a way to impersonate a user that is currently logged on, by retrieving the token with `OpenProcessToken`, duplicating it and calling `WindowsIdentity.Impersonate`. That way I can access the same network resources as the impersonated user.

However, that means my service will only work if there is a logged on user... So I was thinking that, since the LocalSystem has all privileges on the machine, perhaps it can impersonate a user that is not currently logged on ? Or log on as any (local) user without knowing its password ? Assuming it's possible, how can I do it ?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I see the French space between proposition and ? :) Do you have restrictions with "NetworkService"?

Comment: I didn't try with NetworkService, but AFAIK this account has less privileges than LocalSystem, so I'm not sure how it would help me

Comment: take a look if this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/esiu/archive/2005/07/19/eugene.aspx could bring some light.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `WindowsIdentity` constructor taking the username as a string.

Comment: Won't work in my case... the documentation states : *This constructor is intended for use on computers joined only to Windows Server 2003 domains. An exception is thrown for other domain types.*. Apparently I'm not on a Server 2003 domain, since I get a `SecurityException` with the following message : "Incorrect function"

Comment: I think it may be possible with the API call CreateToken(), but I've never tried it.